# ZeroMQ basic Request-Reply implementation

Tags: java, c++, zeromq, jzmq

I'm new to `ZMQ` trying to figure out how to integrate it in my project. I need to implement the most basic request-reply model where the `server is Java` and the `client is C++`. I'm working on `Windows` using `VS2013 and Eclipse (STS)`.
I find the material on the 0MQ overwhelming and confusing. What I'm looking for is a simple list of steps for:

1. Downloading the 0MQ Java - what exactly should I download and from what URL for the most recent stable version.
2. What (location and files) do I need to get into my Eclipse project so that I can begin using 0MQ in my code.
3. Downloading the 0MQ C++ - what exactly should I download and from what URL for the most recent stable version.
4. What (location and files) do I need to get into my VS project so that I can begin using 0MQ in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> - Downloading the 0MQ Java
> - What (location and files) do I need to get into my Eclipse project so that I can begin using 0MQ in my code.

If you're just testing stuff out, the easiest way to get Java working is with [JeroMq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq); it's a full Java implementation of ZeroMq with identical API's. Configure with pom/maven, that's it. For production code, you'll want to build the java bindings for your target OS, but don't worry about that now.

> - Downloading the 0MQ C++
> - What (location and files) do I need to get into my VS project...

This is the hard part. If you can use C# instead of C++, check out [NetMq](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq), a native implementation of ZeroMq in C# for .net. Otherwise, for C++ Visual Studio, you'll have to google around and piece together instructions, you can start [here](http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2013-July/022136.html).

Hope it helps,